# Perl:Selecting an item by right cllick mouse on folder in Windows

Tags: windows, perl, mouseevent, win32gui, win32ole

As a part of my automation test, I have to right click on a folder and select one of the option using Perl in Windows10.

Go to 'C:\MyProject\', Right-Click on 'logs' present there and select 'Pin to Start' (as an example).

I have followed some of the examples mentioned here - https://www.perl.com/pub/2005/08/11/win32guitest.html/ and here - https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GuiTest::Examples. I tried it to do using Win32::GuiTest.

I am able to open the explorer with the directory, select the folder and do right click.
However, I am unable to select the option after right click.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Win32::GuiTest qw(:ALL);

$Win32::GuiTest::debug = 0;

sub bring_window_to_front {
     my $window  = shift;
     my $success = 1;

     if ( SetActiveWindow($window) ) {
         print "* Successfully set the window id: $window active\n";
     }
     else {
         print "* Could not set the window id: $window active\n";
         $success = 0;
     }
     if ( SetForegroundWindow($window) ) {
         print "* Window id: $window brought to foreground\n";
     }
     else {
         print "* Window id: $window could not be brought to foreground\n";
         $success = 0;
     }
     return $success;
}

my $explorer_path = "%windir%/explorer.exe";
my $folder_path = "C:\\MyProject";

# Open the location
system ($explorer_path, $folder_path);
sleep 2;

my @whnds = FindWindowLike( undef, "^MyProject", "" );
if( !@whnds ){
    die "Cannot find window with title/caption MyProject\n";
}
else{
    printf( "Window handle of MyProject is %x\n", $whnds[ 0 ] );
}

sleep 2;

# select the logs directory
SendKeys("logs");
# Send the right click button
SendKeys("{APP}");
sleep 2;

#### Till here everything is working fine
#### I am able to do right click, but unable to select any option. Hitting a road block here
#### Tried these but no result

# MouseClick('Pin to Start');
# MenuSelect('Pin to Start');
# PushChildButton($whnds[ 0 ],"Pin to Start");
```

One thing I am still wondering, whether I am going in right direction.
Am I using the right module or this work is for some other modules(Win32::GUI or Win32::OLE ?).

Comment: I don't use Perl, but in C++/Win32 it is done with **SHILCreateFromPath**  and **SHCreateDefaultContextMenu**